# JS If statement not working on android 4.4.2 or iphone

Tags: javascript, android, iphone

on my android or on a iPhone I will get the else when I type glass  on my computer it works fine

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var x = prompt("Wholesale users enter in the password or hit enter for consumer information "," ");
if(x == "glass"){
    window.alert("sometext");
    }
else {
    window.alert("else");
}
 </script>
```

Comment: Can you be more clear about what you mean by "not working".

Comment: on my android or on a iPhone I will get the else when I type glass on my computer it works fine

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
if([x] == "glass"){
```

should be

```
if(x == "glass"){
```

When you do `[x]`, you are creating an array. Since you are using a == check it will be true. === it would not be true.

---

And from the comments there is a %20 aka whitespace

Change the prompt so you do not have the whitespace in it

```
r information "," ");
```

to

```
r information ","");
```

Comment: sorry I was trying everything to get this to work it doesn't work either way

Comment: `alert(escape(x));` what does it display?

Comment: There is your answer, there is a whitespace!

Comment: Thank you for further explaining! I had eliminated every possibility and it worked, so wasn't sure exactly..